# how can I connect to an ipv4 host with ipv6 request?

Tags: proxy, ipv6, ipv4

Although most of the hosts have ipv6 address now, there are still some hosts that only have ipv4. In my LAN, connections using ipv4 will cost money, while connections using ipv6 is free. I want to implement a proxy to convert ipv4 and ipv6 request, so that I can connect to ipv4 host free. 
Is it possible to implement that? And is there any available software?

Answer (score 3):

This largely depends on the devices, services/protocols and the direction you want to connect in.

**NAT64/DNS64**

With NAT64/DNS64 you can let IPv6-only clients connect to IPv4-only servers. The system looks up the name of the server it wants to connect to using the DNS64 server. If the DNS64 server sees that only an IPv4 address is available it will replace the IPv4 address of the server with a special IPv6 address in which it has encoded the original IPv4 address. When the IPv6-only system connects to that IPv6 address the NAT64 router knows that the intention is to connect to the IPv4 address encoded in the IPv6 address and it will set up a NAT session to that IPv4 address. The NAT64 box needs to have both an IPv4 and IPv6 address to be able to do this.

**HTTP Proxy**

If you only want to support HTTP and similar protocols then you might be able to use an HTTP proxy server. It will need to have both an IPv4 and IPv6 address, and your applications/devices need to support using a proxy server. It will work both for IPv4-only clients and IPv6-only servers and vice-versa.

**SOCKS5**

A SOCKS5 proxy server can also be used in the same way that an HTTP proxy server can be used, but with a wider variety of protocols. Your clients need to support it though.

**Other**

There are other more application-specific ways to proxy between IPv4 and IPv6. The few mentioned above are just to give you an idea of common ones.